# Referencing wrong R.java after library addition

Tags: android

After importing the [Slide Menu](https://github.com/johnkil/SideNavigation) library as a library in my application and doing a clean build, all my application's code references the R.java from the library and not the one in my application package.

A way I have found around this is to write the full path of the class such as `com.example.bitmetrics.R` but that is very inconvinient. Is there a proper solution to the problem so I force my local (package-wise) R.java to be referenced instead of the one of the library?

Comment: does your class have an import "library".R statement?

Comment: can you post a snap shot of the same from eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The appt tool merges the lib resources with your proj res.
http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html

See , resource conflicts, sectio in the link for more details